# what is the point of sourcing setup.bash file during installation of ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does sourcing mean ( in simple terms ) and why are we sourcing setup.bash during installation ?
*[ echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc ]*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252715/what-is-the-point-of-sourcing-setup.bash-file-during-installation-of-ros/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What does sourcing mean [..]

This is a rather general question. See [What is the difference between “source script.sh” and “./script.sh”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779756/what-is-the-difference-between-source-script-sh-and-script-sh) on SO and [Bash Prompt HOWTO - Bash Programming and Shell Scripts - Sourcing a File](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) for some background.

> why are we sourcing setup.bash during installation ?

The [Environment Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/DebEnvironment) section of the installation tutorial gives a hint:

> [..] the ROS environment variables are [..] added to your bash session every time a new shell is launched [..]

`setup.bash` (or `.sh` or `.zsh`) sets up your current command interpreter session with the configuration items necessary for ROS to function properly. In other words: it tells `bash` where the ROS programs and libraries are, tells Python where it can find the `rospy` libraries, etc.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1